# Add XML tags into XML with XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, wso2, transformation, wso2-esb

I use WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 and I want to transform JSON to XML, but default transformation is not enough for me. I have this input (transform) XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
              <locations>  
  <location>
      <id>7eaf7</id>
      <name>Biaggio Cafe</name>
      <tags>bar,restaurant,food,establishment</tags>
   </location>
   <location>
      <id>3ef98</id>
      <name>Doltone House</name>
      <tags>food,establishment</tags>
   </location>
      </locations>
```

I want to get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Entries items="2">
    <Item idx = "0">
      <id>7eaf7</id>
          <name>Biaggio Cafe</name>
          <tags>bar,restaurant,food,establishment</tags>
    </Item>
    <Item idx = "1">
          <id>3ef98</id>
          <name>Doltone House</name>
          <tags>food,establishment</tags>
    </Item>
    </Entries>
```

Is it possible to do this with XSLT? Maybe there is other way to do this?

Comment: This can be done with xslt easily. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below also can be used.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:template match="locations"> 
    <Entries items="{count(location)}"> 
      <xsl:for-each select="location"> 
        <Item idx="{position() - 1}"> 
          <id>
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
          </id>  
          <name>
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
          </name>  
          <tags>
            <xsl:value-of select="tags"/>
          </tags> 
        </Item> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </Entries> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `xsl:copy`

**transformer.xsd**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="locations">
        <Entries items="{count(location)}">
            <xsl:for-each select="location">
                <Item idx="{position() - 1}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </Item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Entries>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Example**

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Xslt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dataXML = "data.xml";
        String inputXSL = "transformer.xsd";
        String outputXML = "out.xml";

        Xslt st = new Xslt();
        try {
            st.transform(dataXML, inputXSL, outputXML);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            System.err.println("TransformerConfigurationException");
            System.err.println(e);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            System.err.println("TransformerException");
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void transform(String dataXML, String inputXSL, String outputXML)
            throws TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException {

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
        StreamSource in = new StreamSource(dataXML);
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outputXML);
        transformer.transform(in, out);
        System.out.println("The generated XML file is:" + outputXML);
    }
}
```

**Data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locations>
    <location>
        <id>7eaf7</id>
        <name>Biaggio Cafe</name>
        <tags>bar,restaurant,food,establishment</tags>
    </location>
    <location>
        <id>3ef98</id>
        <name>Doltone House</name>
        <tags>food,establishment</tags>
    </location>
</locations>
```

**out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entries items="2">
    <Item idx="0">
        <id>7eaf7</id>
        <name>Biaggio Cafe</name>
        <tags>bar,restaurant,food,establishment</tags>
    </Item>
    <Item idx="1">
        <id>3ef98</id>
        <name>Doltone House</name>
        <tags>food,establishment</tags>
    </Item>
</Entries>
```

Comment: Same here, you can replace the `xsl:attribute` and just use `<Entries items="{count(locations)}">...` and `<Item idx="{position() - 1}">...`, same effect, but (much) more readable. You can replace the for-each with apply-templates and a matching template to reduce nesting.

Comment: Thanks Abel. Edited my answer :)

Comment: Thx, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested it, but it should be (close to) what you need.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="locations">
  <xsl:element name="Entries">
    <xsl:attribute name="items">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(location)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:for-each select="location">
      <xsl:element name="Item">
        <xsl:attribute name="idx">
          <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
        <tags><xsl:value-of select="tags"/></tags>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Why do you use `id/.`? The `.` means current node, so it has no effect here, just write `id`. And you can replace your `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` with, for instance, `<Entries items="{count(location)}">...`, which is (quite a bit) easier to read. You can replace the for-each with apply-templates to reduce nesting.